# Unit group of group algebra can be identified with the space of function $G \rightarrow k?$

Tags: representation-theory

Consider the group algebra $k[G].$ Supposedly, the unit group $k[G]$ can be identified as the space of functions $G$ to $k.$ I am a little confused by this. Suppose $\sum_{g \in G} a_gg$ is a unit. Then it has an inverse. That is, $\sum_{g \in G} \sum_{h \in G} a_{gh^{-1}}b_h g = 1.$ This means that $\sum_{h \in G}a_{gh^{-1}}b_h = 0$ for $g \neq e$ and 1 otherwise. However, how does this define a function from $G \rightarrow k?$ Furthermore, doesn't such a function define any such element of the group algebra as we can map $g \in G$ to its coefficient?

Comment: I don't know where you got your "supposedly", as the claim is not true. What is in fact true is that the group algebra itself can be identified with that space (with a convolution as multiplication).

Comment: To quote my professor's lecture notes, the space $k[G]^*$ can be identified with the space of functions from $G$ to $k.$

Comment: That star means dual, not units then.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 An exampl ethat whosw that not both $k[G]$ and $k[G]^\times$ can be identified with the space of functions $G\to k$, consider a finite example, such as $k=\Bbb F_2$ and $G=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, and count the three sets in question.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the dual makes a lot of sense - each element of the dual is defined by the image of $g$ - which we can simply identify as a map from $G$ to $k.$ Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Another way to see it is that $k[G] \simeq k^{(G)}$ (as vector spaces) and it is well known that the dual of $k^{(I)}$ is $k^I$ for any set $I$